# {% debug %} Django template tag not working

Tags: django, debugging, django-templates, frontend

I am developing some website for my college reseach departament and while trying to debug with inbuilt tag.

I have a little issue, I´m trying to print some pictures, and use the inbuilt debug Django template tag {% debug %}, but the result is that is printing some awkward lines. There is a screenshot of the ... edited.

[image: if you have any hints]

This is the template:

```
{% extends "modelo_base.html" %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% block title %} NuPEB - Pesquisa em Educação {% endblock %}
{% block comment %}{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/estilos.css' %}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block style %}
    <style>
    </style>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <body>

    <hr/>

**<!-- so if I´m putting the tag anywhere around here it print that
     that nonsense ... -->**
            {% debug %}


        <!-- MOSTRA O JUMBOTRON -->
        <div class="jumbotron col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5" id="titleJumbo" style="display: block;">
            <p>
                Líder: Prof. Dr. Jaime Farias Dresch
            </p>
            <strong>Núcleo de Pesquisa em Educação Básica: políticas e processos formativos </strong>
            <br/>
            <div class="row span-row">
                <div class=" container">
                    <div class="btn-objectives-center">
                        <button class="btn-lg btn-success" id="btn-span-objectives">Objetivos</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        {% comment %} {% load debug_tags %}{% set_trace %} {% endcomment %}
        {% comment %} {% load debug_tags %}    {% endcomment %}
         {% comment %} {% attributes varname %} {% details varname %} {% endcomment %}
        <div class="logo-nupeb col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="display:block;" id="nupeb-logo">
            <img src='{% static 'images/logo_nupeb.jpg' %}' class="imglogo"/>
            {#        <img src='../static/images/logo_nupeb.jpg' class="imglogo" />#}
        </div>

        <!-- MOSTRA OS MEMBROS DO NuPEB-->
        <div>
            <article class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5 col-md-8" id="nupeb-members" style="display: none;">
                <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold"> INTEGRANTES: </h1>
                <br/>
                <h3>Pesquisadores</h3>
                <p> Prof. Dr. Jaime Farias Dresch (líder)
                    <a href="http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K4750497D3">
                        Currículo Lattes
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p>Profa. Dra. Maria Selma Grosch (líder) Currículo Lattes
                    <a href="http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K4771186E1">
                        Currículo Lattes
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p>Profa. Dra. Ana Lúcia Calbaiser da Silva Currículo Lattes
                    <a href="http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K4273586T8">
                        Currículo Lattes
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p>Profa. Ma. Arlene Aparecida de Arruda Currículo Lattes
                    <a href="http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.do?metodo=apresentar&id=K4739990Z4">
                        Currículo Lattes
                    </a>
                </p>

                <h3>Estudantes</h3>
                <p> Claudia Teresinha Pagno Puerari (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Daniela Meurer Goulart (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Denise Cristiane do Nascimento Vieira (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Gislaine Aparecida de Matos (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Letícia Arruda (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Lucimar Presotto Azi Costa (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Janilde Crestani (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Viviane de Lourdes Costa Rosa dos Santos (Mestrado em Educação) </p>
                <p> Monica Teresinha Farias Muniz (graduação - Jornalismo) </p>
                <p> Simone Mara Dulz (Mestrado em Educação) </p>

                <h3>Egresso</h3>
                <p> Ramon Dal Lanho de Oliveira (graduação - Medicina) </p>
            </article>

            <br/>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your templates?

Comment: @franndyabreu, I just editted to show the template... thanks in advance